# Change permissions of postgres copy to exported file

Tags: postgresql, linux, export, copy

I have asked this question on SO but perhaps that was the wrong location. Apologies for double posting but the question may have a better audience here.

The original question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619290/change-permissions-of-postgres-copy-to-exported-file

And the text is below. Thanks.

---

When running the postgresql [9.3] "COPY TO" functionality, the postgres user creates a file. I have told it to put the file in the tmp directory (although this can be changed if needed).

This is run as part of a cron job, the user is an "export" user set up especially for this task. The end goal is for the exported file to end up in /home/export/created_file.csv.

1) `postgres` can't stash the exported file straight into the home directory of another user without setting up the folder to be overly permissive.

2) the export user can copy the file from `/tmp` to it's home directory, but then can not clean up (delete) the `postgres` owned file in `/tmp`.

This is a daily process and so old files will need to be deleted in some way. I can add a cron job to clean up the files afterwards but I was hoping for a cleaner solution - either a way to change the permissions on the file that `postgres` creates, or some way to give the export user the additional permission of being able to delete that file in advance of it's creation.

Giving the export user the same permissions as `postgres` in general however isn't an option, as it would then have free reign over the database.

Any advice, be it unix based or postgres based would be very welcome, thanks.

Comment: Please delete the old question.

Comment: Original SO question deleted.

Comment: ...and link to old question on SO too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to create a directory without the [`t` (sticky) permissions bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) set, and have PostgreSQL copy the file into there. You should also make the directory setgid (`g+s`), as that makes the group inherited from the directory, not the creating process; see [setgid directories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories).

You could put this directory in `/tmp` but personally I'd put it some neutral location like `/var/lib`, or mounted volume somewhere, as `/tmp` gets cleaned out automatically so you'll need to have the directory re-created if it's missing.

Assuming you do use `/tmp`:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/pgcsv
chgrp users /tmp/pgcsv
chmod u=rwX,g=rwsX,o= /tmp/pgcsv
```

then create the csv in there. It'll be automatically created with group-owner `users`, which will make it readable by your users (unless PostgreSQL's `umask` is too restrictive). Because the directory is group-writable by `users` (or whatever group you use) *and does not have the `t` (sticky) bit set* your users can delete files they do not own from it.

The reason this doesn't work when using `/tmp/` directly is that the sticky bit is set in `/tmp` for security, so that user1 can't delete a file created by user2 and replace it with a symlink that user2 then writes to, allowing user1 to steal their data / trick them into overwriting things.

---

Other options:

- Run the cron job as user `export`, using `psql`'s `\copy` command, so it writes the data over the client/server socket and the file is created as the `export` user in the first place. This is by far the simplest option, and only slightly slower than a direct `COPY`.
- Have a cron job running as `root` invoke the PostgreSQL `copy` then move the data file and change its ownership once the `COPY` finishes.
- Give the export user the ability to run a very restricted command as root via `sudo` to move/delete.
- Use POSIX ACLs to grant the `postgres` user special permission to write to `/home/export` (if POSIX ACLs are enabled on your file system)
- Set group-owner of `/home/export` to `postgres` and make its permissions `g=wx`. PostgreSQL can add new entries, and overwrite anything within that it has write permission to, but not list entries. I don't like this option much.

Comment: A very well documented answer, thank you. There are at least some options that I would never have known about, and at least a couple I'm kicking myself for not having thought of. Many thanks.

Comment: Sticky bit was it

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably super late for this, but I just want to add this in case someone else gets stuck:

Since the program you're running in `COPY TO PROGRAM` is just a regular bash command that receives the result of the select as its input, you could just append a chmod and change file permissions before being done with the file.

For example, you could change:

```
COPY (SELECT * from ...) TO PROGRAM 'gzip > my_new_file'
```

to

```
COPY (SELECT * from ...) TO PROGRAM 'gzip > my_new_file_path && chmod 755 my_new_file_path'
```

and that would set permissions to the file before finishing the copy.

Comment: That would have been mighty useful answer, thank you! But you're right in that you're a little late for me :-)

Comment: Great answer. I would also add that, if you don't want your output file to be zipped, you can just replace `gzip` with `cat`.

Comment: Even later :-).  I'd use [GNU coreutils install](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/install-invocation.html) instead for the `TO PROGRAM`  e.g. `install -m=755 /dev/stdin my_new_file_path`. Games with file/group ownership still need to be played if `postgres` doesn't belong to a desired group.